# JavaScript/regex: Remove characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Can someone show me a way to convert

```
moveForward('block_id_~T_o|qZc=[B}}[p5qej5'); 
turnLeft('block_id_r21iJfS8+9W6?pnK/=sA'); 
moveForward('block_id_hDK1xef|j[E2X6N{M[}o'); 
turnRight('block_id_R9g=)oLUt|^|gPSr!XU^'); 
moveForward('block_id_AS124O%V`/$a4o6ZyhQ8');
```

to

```
moveForward(); 
turnLeft(); 
moveForward(); 
turnRight(); 
moveForward();
```

and

```
while (notDone()) {
 moveForward('block_id_p5Zhkkmn[TSboZ83#PNG');
}
```

to

```
while (notDone()) {
  moveForward();
}
```

using JavaScript with Regex or any other way?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it would be. As long as there are parentheses inside your strings, it's even trivial. But if that's not the answer you wanted, remember to [follow the posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) and remember to post only _after_ searching the web and stackoverflow for answers. This has been asked plenty of times before, so it sounds like you haven't searched for answers first, yet.

Comment: Are you trying to edit javascript source code with javascript?

Comment: Regex is easy. https://regex101.com/r/ZwdwIr/1 You can use this in any editor like VScode who can handle Regex.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why you want to use something as a string in your code that already looks like a code, here's the solution anyways:

Regex:

```
(?<![\w])(moveForward|turnLeft|turnRight)\('[^']*'\)
```

JS example:

```js
let str = `moveForward('block_id_~T_o|qZc=[B}}[p5qej5'); 
turnLeft('block_id_r21iJfS8+9W6?pnK/=sA'); 
moveForward('block_id_hDK1xef|j[E2X6N{M[}o'); 
turnRight('block_id_R9g=)oLUt|^|gPSr!XU^'); 
moveForward('block_id_AS124O%V\`/$a4o6ZyhQ8');

while (notDone()) {
 moveForward('block_id_p5Zhkkmn[TSboZ83#PNG');
}`

let newStr = str.replace(/(?<![\w])(moveForward|turnLeft|turnRight)\('[^']*'\)/g, "$1()");

console.log(newStr);
```

If you want to replace part of your (actual) code, you can use [visual studio code](http://code.visualstudio.com/) (or any code editor that lets you find and replace using regex)

[image: visual studio code]

Comment: Hi, sorry for editing the question, but I don't think your answer will work always as I have shown in the edited part.